# Proxmox container can't reach internet

Tags: proxmox

I have new installed proxmox instance. But when I created new container I can't reach internet.

When I try do package update I got

```
root@pve:~# apt-get update
Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

When I try ping google I got

```
root@pve:~# ping google.pl
ping: google.pl: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

My network configuration on container

```
root@pve:~# cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# --- BEGIN PVE ---
search learn-linux.eu
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
# --- END PVE ---
```

My network configuration for proxmox
[image]
My DNS configuration

[image]

Any idea what I did wrong?

Comment: You have a public IP on your container - it should be a local address.

Comment: @Orphans

How can I add local address? When I add new network vmbr1 and add local ip i.e. 192.168.10.100/24 and use this interface on my lxc, I got  ```net0: unable to hotplug net0: no physical interface on bridge 'vmbr1'```

Comment: You have to configure a local network, and the NAT it out.

Comment: @Orphans Thanks for answer, but this is too difficult for me :)

Answer (score 0):

You may have to set your container to use DHCP, so that it gets a proper IP address.

[image: Proxmox configuration for container network. IPV4: DHCP]